# Stuck on a beginner proof writing: If $U = A \cup B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $A = U \setminus B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

While I was trying to work on the proof, I realized I never ended up using the second given,  $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Then I realized my logic could be off entirely, but I'm not entirely too sure what about it needs fixing.

I'll be tackling the first part since that doesn't really seem to make sense. 
**Feel free to not focus on the wording, and just aid with the logic portion of it.**

Hello future reader! If you encounter this ~1 week of after I posted it, that means I temporarily took it off because I do have to submit it and can be plagiarized (regardless of the difficulty of the proof- it is a full solution that is written in my style). It'll be up in ~1 week as I said, I'd definitely like to keep it for someone unless to learn basic set theory proofs in the future!

Comment: If x ∈ A in the first case, wouldn't it show that A ⊆ U since we know it can't be B, and we already know x ∈ U? Wouldn't it be similar for the second "1st case:"; If x ∈ A, since it was derived from x ∈ U originally using U = A ∪ B, then U ⊆ A, where we can disregard set B?

Answer (score 0):

(i) "then let's assume $x \in U \setminus B$." No, you want to **prove** $x \in U \setminus B$ using the assumption $x \in A$.
By definition of set difference, you want to **prove** that $x \in U$ and $x \notin B$.

The rest looks fine.

Comment: That makes sense, but then would I keep what I have with the cases? If I'm using x ∈ A to prove that x∈U∖B is true, would I still use U = A ∪ B?

Comment: @RivelAn Yes, certainly.  That is how you claim that $x\in A$ entails that $x\in U$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is not bad, but it's too wordy. One can make it shorter by first noting that

$$(A \cup B) - B = A - (A \cap B) \hspace{20px}(\star)$$

So, when $A \cap B = \emptyset$, we get $(A \cup  B) - B = A$.

To prove $\star$, let's take $x \in (A \cup B) - B$, we can write down:

$x \in (A \cup B ) - B \iff (x \in A \text{ or }x\in B) \text{ and }x \not\in B \iff x \in A \text{ and } x \not\in B$.

The last one says that $x$ is in $A$, but it cannot be in $B$. This equivalently means that the elements of $B$ that are in $A$ are excluded. Since $B$ in general is not a subset of $A$ writing this down as $x \in A - B$ doesn't seem right but it can be equivalently written down as $x \in A-(A\cap B)$

Comment: I've been told to write it as formally as possible with sentences just to get familiar with the logical steps. I _think_ I get what you're expressing, but how would I have come up with that I need to break down A\B = A\B into (A∪B)−B=A−(A∩B) to manipulate it to find the solution? Or just finding shortcuts overall in proof writing? Aside, so the cases of arguments work, regardless of wordiness? I've been having trouble with trying to actually prove stuff within the cases.

Comment: @RivelAn I can't give you a general idea for all problems, but I can tell you how I came up with this one. I asked myself what $(A \cup B) - B$ is equal to. Pondering over the problem for a few seconds, you can see that $B$ cancels not only all the elements that are in $B$ but also those elements in $A$ that are in common with $B$. Hence, what we're left with are those elements of $A$ that are not in $B$. Expressing this in the language of set theory is that $(A \cup B) - B = A - (A \cap B)$. Then I tried to justify why this equality holds step by step formally.

Comment: Hmm I see, thank you!

Comment: @RivelAn  You're welcome. I would also like to add that after solving problems in a certain area of math for some time, you develop some sort of intuition that helps you find solutions to a problem in that area more efficiently. So, to give a partial answer to your question about how you can find shortcuts in proof writing, I'd like to say that the only guaranteed way I know to achieve this is through practice. It takes time though.